# Lattice homomorphism induced by topology homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lattice-orders

My book mentions this. However, I am not seeing why 1. and 2. are true. I guess part of the problem is that the lattice (homomorphic) map induced by the continuous topology map isn't even defined on the book (it isn't on Section 1.4.9 either). Can anyone tell me how is it usually defined, and maybe help in the subsequent statements too?

[image: Lattice map induced by continuous topology map]

Comment: This is essentially the definition of continuity: if $U$ is open in  $Y$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. So the lattice map can just be defined as $f^{-1}$. It's not hard to see that this is indeed a lattice homomorphism. Knowing what the lattice map is, can you then prove 1) and 2)?

Comment: So are you saying that the "lattice map" they refer to is from $\tau_{2}$ to $\tau_{1}$ and not the other way? as that's the only map I can see defining from $f^{-1}$ If so I would see that map actually satisfying 1. and 2. !

Comment: Yup, check closely on lines 4-5: "such a map induces a homomorphism from the lattice $\tau_2$ into the lattice $\tau_1$".

Comment: Oh true, my bad for not reading it well! Now it makes sense.

Comment: If you can, you should write up the solutions to 1. and 2. and post them as an answer to take this question off the unanswered list. :)

Comment: I'm probably being dense, but if $X=Y=\{0,1\}$, $\tau_1$ is the discrete topology, $\tau_2$ is the trivial topology, and $f\colon X\to Y$ is the identity map, then $f$ is continuous one-to-one, but the induced map $f_*\colon\tau_2\to\tau_1$ is a map from a $2$-element set to a $4$-element set, so can't be surjective. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, are you sure that's continuous? A continuous map requires that a set in $Y$ is open if the inverse image is open, so you'd need ${0}$ and ${1}$ to ben open in $Y$ too.

Comment: @DanielRust 1) seems intuitively to me like it should be false for "most" non-open maps... (translating it into point-set language: given any open set $U \subset X$, there's an open set $V \subset Y$ such that $f(U) \subset V$ and $\text{im}(f) \cap V = f(U)$. This seems like it should fail pretty darn often when $f$ isn't an open map.)

Comment: @DanielRust No, guillefix, Daniel is right. Continuity only requires that the inverse image of every open set is open; it does not require the converse. Statement 1 in the book is wrong.

Comment: True. Thanks for correcting my definition of continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the lattice map is the *inverse set map*, $f^{-1}(A) = \{ x \in X | f(x) \in A \}$ from $\tau_{2}$ to $\tau_{1}$. As also pointed out by @DanielRust in the comments, the first statement is false as he gives a valid counter-example.

My proof for the second statement would be:

Take two open sets in $\tau_{2}$, $U$ and $V$. Take $f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(V) = A \in \tau_{2}$ (as $f$ is continuous) Now, from the definition of $f^{-1}$, $f(A) = \{f(x) | x \in A \} \subset U, V$. Now, take $y \in U$. Because $f$ is surjective, $y = f(x')$ for some $x' \in X$. But this implies that $x' \in f^{-1}(U)$ and thus that $y \in f(A)$. Therefore, $U \subset f(A)$, which can be similarly shown for $V$. This, at once, shows that $U = f(A) = V$, and that $f^{-1}$ is surjective.

I am just beginning to self-learn set-based maths, so this is among my first such proofs I try to construct, I hope it's well done! :)